# tikz-cd arrows not aligned horizontally as expected

Tags: tikz-cd

I have the following code

```
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=tiny]
    & (\nu d,\, e)(\bar{b} \langle e \rangle \,|\,\bar{d}) \not\downarrow_c \\
(\nu d,\, e)\bar{b} \langle d \rangle \,|\, \bar{b} \langle e \rangle \,|\, b(x).\bar{x} \arrow[ur] \arrow[dr] & \\
    & (\nu d,\, e)(\bar{b} \langle d \rangle \,|\,\bar{e}) \not\downarrow_c \\
\end{tikzcd}
```

and for some reason, the 2 arrows have different starting points horizontally. I tried making the second row a node and add `cells={nodes={anchor=east}}`, but the issue persists. Any idea how to fix this? Also very strange issue because if I delete a few characters from the second row, it seems to have the intended behaviour.

[image]

Edit: Fixed inconsistency that Marijn pointed out

Comment: Unrelated but your code and your screenshot differ in the use of an open parenthesis before _b_ on the left.

Comment: `anchor=east` specifies the placement of a node, not the start point of a line (unless in a `node cs:`). TikZ-CD uses an `asymmetrical rectangle` so that horizontal arrows stay horizontal despite different node sizes. You could change it back to `rectangle` for this diagram …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different anchors than the default center.

I also removed all `\,` commands and used `\mid`; in order to improve the horrible output of `\not\downarrow`, I employed `\centernot`.

Note: there's an unbalanced parenthesis in the term on the left. Fix it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{centernot}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=tiny]
  & (\nu d, e)(\bar{b} \langle e \rangle \mid \bar{d}) \mathrel{\centernot\downarrow}_c \\
(\nu d, e)(\bar{b} \langle d \rangle \mid \bar{b} \langle e \rangle \mid b(x).\bar{x}
  \arrow[ur,start anchor=north east,end anchor=base west]
  \arrow[dr,start anchor=south east,end anchor=real west] &
\\
  & (\nu d, e)(\bar{b} \langle d \rangle \mid \bar{e}) \mathrel{\centernot\downarrow}_c \\
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! If you have time, could you please explain why this was happening in the first place? I find it weird that it works if the text before is shorter

Comment: @Filu The arrows start from the center and appear outside the (invisible) frame that `tikz-cd` puts around the object.